# Notepad++ Ctrl+Shift+Right should select until the beginning (not end) of a word

Tags: notepad++

I love NPP, but it has always struck me as different that it selects until the *end* of a word when using `Ctrl+Shift+Right` instead of to the beginning (similar effect with `Ctrl+Shift+Left`.)

I looked through the settings but didn't spot it. Is there a way to change its behaviour?

Comment: The Ctrl+Shift combos are for selecting *words*, not for selecting white space.

Comment: "as different that it selects until the end of a word...", different to what apps?

Comment: @harrymc I never said it wasn't for words.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio MS Word, text fields in web browsers, Git Extensions. Can you name one that acts like NPP?

Comment: So, you want Ctrl+Shift+Right (or Ctrl+Shift+Left) to select the word and the space before the next (previous) word? If yes, does Word do it for Ctrl+Shift+Left?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes, I guess you could say that MS apps, and browsers for that matter, at least in Windows, jump from the beginning of one word to the beginning of the next/previous word, though some, like browsers, treat delimiter characters differently from Word, for instance. Admittedly, I'm after what I'm used to, not what is "correct". I'd be curious if any other apps act like NPP, though to harrymc's point below, I guess all Scintilla-based apps will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ is built on Scintilla which doesn't have this selection method found in Microsoft's Office.

See
[Scintilla Documentation](https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html)
for operations like SCI_WORDLEFTEXTEND and SCI_SCI_WORDPARTRIGHTEXTEND
and the contained definition of "Words".

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Found it in: Settings > Shortcut mapper > Scintilla commands > SCI_WORDLEFTEXTEND and SCI_WORDRIGHTEXTEND.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou to harrymc! To elaborate on harrymc's answer for others, I tested this and what you need to do is remove the shortcut for SCI_WORDRIGHT**ENDEXTEND** and instead assign the shortcut (Ctrl+Shift+Right) to SCI_WORDRIGHT**EXTEND**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).